# conditional defining static variables

Tags: c, static, macros, conditional-statements, c-preprocessor

Looking for a way to make conditional static declaration.
I want to make some variables in my program static when compiling in release and global for testing while compiling in debug.
Since I don't want all my static variables to turn global when debugging so I thought maybe I could do a macro that defines a variable static according to a compiling flag. I want something like this:

```
#define STATIC(def) (def) ? : static
```

Can something like this be done? 
Using C standard 89

Comment: isn't the conditional operator is run-time one?

Answer (score 3):

How about using a preprocessor `#if`? You could do something like this:

```
#if YOUR_CONDITION
#define STATIC(def) static def
#else
#define STATIC(def) def
#endif
```

You could, in your case, also use `#ifdef` and `#ifndef`:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE /*Define as static when DEBUG_MODE is defined*/
#define STATIC(def) static def
#else
#define STATIC(def) def
#endif
```